# mkdir permissions needed for script called by systemctl start service

Tags: permissions, systemd, amazon-ec2, systemd-journald, amazon-linux

> **How can I give `mkdir` permissions to a script that is called by `sudo systemctl start <service-name>` ??**

Here is the error being thrown in the results of `sudo journalctl -u jekyll -f` when I type the `sudo systemctl start jekyll` command:

```
Mar 20 18:29:52 long.host.name jekyll[5280]: /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /.jekyll-cache (Errno::EACCES)
```

I then opened `/usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb` and saw that the directories to be created were in the `/usr/local/lib/ruby` path.  Since `/usr/local/lib/` already existed, I typed the following two commands to remove all obstacles to anyone writing to these directories:

```
sudo chown -R jekyll-host:jekyll-host /usr/local/lib  
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib
```

And then I also separately upgraded to root with `sudo su -` and I ran the `systemctl start jekyll` command as root, but even this resulted in the same permissions error shown above.

The line in the `jekyll.service` file that attempts to start this server but throws the above error is:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/jekyll s --trace'
```

As you can surmise, the `/usr/local/bin/jekyll` program called in the `ExecStart` command in turn calls other scripts including the `/usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb` script shown above which does not seem to have permissions to create a directory.

This is running on an EC2 instance with Amazon Linux 2, which of course is an extension of RHEL.

> **What specific syntax needs to be changed in order to adequate permissions to be propagated throughout the chain of programs that are called when this `sudo systemctl start jekyll` command is run?**

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> /.jekyll-cache
> ```

Your program is trying to create a directory in the root of the filesystem.  This is not a permissions problem, and it would be very daft indeed to "solve" it by granting any write rights to the root directory.

This is a configuration problem, of some kind, either in your service's own configuration or in the systemd service unit.  Find out why your service incorrectly thinks that the root directory is the place to create its cache directory.  Fix *that*.